# I knew I would have died/ I knew I would die

Tags: grammar, verbs, would, would-have-been

I'm writing a story and my character is referring to the knowledge she always had that she would eventually die under the rain. Of course she's not dead at the moment of saying the sentence, but she may be about to die. She feels sure about dying, but she is actually not going to.

How should I phrase this sentence? and what rules do apply in this case?

Comment: Both are correct—depending on context and personal choice. There is no "correct" answer to this as it's stated.

Comment: 'I knew I would have died' seems odd to me, as it implies that the character was thinking of her own death as having occurred in the past. 'I knew I would die/was going to die' is better.